# Help with horizontal Tikz Tree Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I need to plot something like this [image: Tikz picture]

So far I have been able to plot using the codes below. I could not find a way to include a vertical tree

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw,rounded corners,fill=red!30,text width=18mm,minimum height=9mm,align=center,drop shadow},
>=Stealth,level distance = 30mm,sibling distance=13mm]

\begin{scope}[grow'=right,edge from parent fork right,->]
\node (root) at (0,0) {}
child  {node (b1) {B}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[grow=left,edge from parent fork left,->]
\node (root) at (0,0) {Loschmidt Echo}
child  {node (a1) {C}};
\end{scope}            
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add arrows:

- use library `arrows.meta`
- define a drawing style, e.g. `arr`
- use for formatting connections

Please find more details in the `tikz` manuals, e.g. in the minimal introduction, ch. 3.3: https://ctan.org/pkg .

[image: with arrows]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}% <<<

\begin{document}
  \tikz [draw, 
         box/.style = 
         { 
           fill=red!30,
           minimum width=18mm,       
         },
         rnd/.style =
         { 
           rounded corners,
           fill=red!30,
           minimum width=18mm,       
         },
         arr/.style={->, >=Latex}% <<<
        ] {
    \node [box] (root) at (0,0) {C (root)};
    \node [rnd] (D) [below=of root] {D};
    \node [box] (A) [right=of root] {A};
    
    \draw [arr] (root) -- (D);% <<<
    \draw [arr] (root) -- (A);
  }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something more simple, e.g. like this, which is only one way to do it. And please ... provide complete code.

Changes I introduced:

- abandoned the child&sibling idea
- defined node-styles as needed
- used relative positioning

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
  \tikz [draw, 
         box/.style = 
         { 
           fill=red!30,
           minimum width=18mm,       
         },
         rnd/.style =
         { 
           rounded corners,
           fill=red!30,
           minimum width=18mm,       
         }       
        ] {
    \node [box] (root) at (0,0) {C (root)};
    \node [rnd] (D) [below=of root] {D};
    \node [box] (A) [right=of root] {A};
    
    \draw (root) -- (D);
    \draw (root) -- (A);
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you @MS-SPO ... Can you suggest how can I use arrows instead of lines to join the boxes?